# Bootstrap button and navigation bar not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, navigation

I'm a noob in this kind of thing, I don't understand what thing I'm doing wrong. I don't get a button nor a navigation bar; all I get is a small button that doesn't do absolutely nothing and is not with the color that I put in my CSS. My navigation bar doesn't appear neither. Btw, is bootstrap good or is there a program better?

My code is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the url is correct? Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SITE NAME/LOGO</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">HEADING1<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HEADING2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HEADING3</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">HEADING4<span class="caret"></span></a>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#bmiform">SomeThing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SomeThingElse</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SomeThingElse</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">SomeThingElse</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">SomeThingElse</a></li>
              </ul>

            </li>
          </ul>

          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
          </form>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">SomeThingElse</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

It is also better practice to use bootstrap from its online source. It makes your site faster because other sites request the same resource and it so it is stored in browsers cache.

Bootstrap is a good tool and can make building websites alot faster and easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit this if you are using Bootstrap 3. And Yes it is great ;)

You just insert the start of Bootstrap Navigation. Use all of it.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>

    </nav>
```